# chroot, gpg-agent, and Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: sftp, chroot, ubuntu-18.04, gnupg

For SFTP access to my server, I have created a sftp user that is limited to a working directory by `chroot`.

```
Match User sftp-user
    AuthorizedKeysFile /home/sftp-user/.ssh/authorized_keys
    ChrootDirectory /var/www/domain
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no
```

And this entry in `/etc/passwd`

```
sftp-user:x:1003:1003::/html:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

There were some issues with the key file, but setting an absolute path for that solved the issue. The SFTP login worked fine until - I do not exactly know - the nagios server monitoring was installed on the server (a VPS) and/or updates have been run, and the system has been rebooted.

Now, connection fails and the `syslog` shows this error:

```
systemd[7590]: gpgconf: running /usr/bin/gpg-agent failed (exitcode=2): General error
systemd[7590]: gpgconf: fatal error (exit status 1)
```

This error occurs no matter if the login is done via key file or password. So I have tried following the question [gpg-agent says agent exists, but gpg says agent doesn't exist?](https://serverfault.com/questions/481103/gpg-agent-says-agent-exists-but-gpg-says-agent-doesnt-exist) to narrow down the problem.

```
$ gpg-agent --version
gpg-agent (GnuPG) 2.2.4
libgcrypt 1.8.1
```

When I started `gpg-agent` as user (not the sftp user), it creates a file in the home directory on the first run:

```
$ gpg -d demo-file.asc
gpg: keybox '/home/username/.gnupg/pubring.kbx' created
```

When I disable the `chroot` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, the login works properly. So I assume, that some access fails in the chroot session. As the sftp user is not allowed to use a shell, I did not `bind` any directories into the sftp-user's home directory.

Answer (score 4):

It actually was the `.gnupg` directory that could not be created. The home directory specified in `/etc/passwd` (`/html`) is relative during the SFTP session, but understood as absolute path during the login. Therefore...

- Creating a folder `.gnupg` in chroot+home = `/var/www/domain/html` did not (!) help.
- Creating a folder `/html/.gnupg` (`.gnupg` owned by sftp-user) removed the error message from `/syslog`.

To take care of further problems (of course, it did not work immediately), I started another `sshd` daemon in verbose mode and connected to this port .... but that would lead off topic here.

```
sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -d -p 3321
```