# gpg-agent: fatal error in syslog on ssh login

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, gpg

In the `syslog` for my Ubuntu server, there is an error that appears whenever I log in using an SSH user account.

```
systemd[27299]: usr/bin/gpg-agent failed (exitcode=2): General error
systemd[27299]: gpgconf: fatal error (exit status 1)
systemd[27299]: Listening on GnuPG network certificate management daemon.
systemd[27299]: Reached target Timers.
systemd[27299]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (access for web browsers).
systemd[27299]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (restricted).
systemd[27299]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent (ssh-agent emulation).
systemd[27299]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache.
```

I don't really know what's happening here, because I don't know what is GnuPG or `gpg-agent`. I've found a thread in HowToForge where the user has a similar issue, and an answerer mentions something about OSSEC and something about `ispconfig`, which I didn't understand: https://www.howtoforge.com/community/threads/error-message-when-logging-in-via-ssh.81005/

Will the `gpgconf` error pose a security issue? How do I fix it? Can someone also explain what `gpg-agent` does?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the issue. It's actually because I set the home directory to a folder that the user doesn't have permissions over. This caused the system to be unable to create `.gnupg` in the home folder, causing the error.

Found the answer here: [chroot, gpg-agent, and Ubuntu 18.04](https://serverfault.com/questions/954844/chroot-gpg-agent-and-ubuntu-18-04).